# How to add a datepicker for a custom field from system configuration

Tags: magento-1, datepicker

I follower this [tutorial](https://www.integer-net.com/how-to-create-tables-in-magento-system-configuration/).  You can add easily fields as input text or dropdown, but in my case I want to add the magento datepicker.

I have this function :

```
public function _prepareToRender()
{
        $this->addColumn('holiday_name', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule')->__('Name'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
            'renderer' => $this->_getRendererDate(),
        ));
}
protected function  _getRendererDate()
{
        if (!$this->_itemRenderer) {
            $this->_itemRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'mynamespace_mymodule/config_adminhtml_form_field_holidaydate', '',
                array('is_render_to_js_template' => true)
            );
        }
        return $this->_itemRenderer;
}
```

and this is my block, which extends this class: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field`

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date;
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

        $data = array(
            'name'      => $element->getName(),
            'html_id'   => $element->getId(),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        );
        $date->setData($data);
        $date->setValue($element->getValue(), $format);
        $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));
        $date->setForm($element->getForm());

        return $date->getElementHtml();
    }
```

This is not working, any ideas how can make this work ? thx

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldset->addField('purchase_date', 'date', array(
                'name'               => 'date',
                'label'              => Mage::helper('usercontact')->__('Purchase Date'),
                'tabindex'           => 1,
                'image'              => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                'format'             => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT) ,
                'value'              => date( Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateStrFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
                                              strtotime('next weekday') )
            ));
```

you use this code to add datepicker field in your form

Comment: ok, where should I add this ? Did you check the article ?

Comment: when you create form in admin that time this code is used.